# How to right-align text in a grammar environment?

Tags: spacing, syntax, grammar

Using the `grammar` environment of the `syntax` package, I cannot find a way to right-align text in my syntax definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<expression> ::=
\alt <expression> $+$ <expression>         (addition)
\alt <expression> $*$ <expression>   (multiplication)
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

I would like for `(addition)` and `(multiplication)` to be right-aligned in the output. The closest answer I could find was:
[Grammar with numbered rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102808/grammar-with-numbered-rules)

But I could not understand the solution nor reproduce it for this case. It seems like this part would almost do the trick:

```
\hskip\dimexpr\linewidth-\labelwidth+\grammarindent-\labelsep
```

But I can't find a way to have the proper value...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please, always post compilable code i.e. a complete example. You can edit your question to complete your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `\hfill` seems to do the job (`showframe` is just for visual guideline):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<expression> ::= <ident>
\alt <expression> $+$ <expression>         \hfill (addition)
\alt <expression> $*$ <expression>   \hfill  (multiplication)
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

[image]